# How do you handle constants, that are shared over lambdas?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda

Is there a smart way to share constants over differet lambdas?

I could use environment variables, but i don't want to make them configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use Lambda Layers. You can define a Lambda Layer with the constants you need to use in different lambdas.

Take the following as a layer example and call it `constants` (in Javascript):

```
let constants = {
  // conversion factor from GB to Bytes
  GB_TO_BYTE: 1073741824
};

module.exports = constants;
```

Then in order to use it in your lambdas, you must configure each Lambda with this layer. And in the lambda itself, you can get the constant value as follows:

```
const constants = require('constants');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(constants.GB_TO_BYTE)
    };
    return response;
};
```

The previous Lambda will use `constants.GB_TO_BYTE` as your constant throughout the code. This layer can obviously be used in all the other lambdas which need the constants defined in the layer.

Comment: This will work, but not the ideal way to share constants as layers are not easily changed. A "smart" way to share keys in AWS resources is to use the Systems Manager Parameter Store or Secrets Manager, as they offer KMS encrypted keys and can do things like automated key rotation. Also IMO much easier to implement than a lambda layer and can be used by ec2

Answer (score 4):

As an option you may check [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html)

Comment: Or the AWS Secrets Manager service https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

Comment: Our problem with that is, it is quiet slow

Comment: You should cache variables, thus during warm state of lambda you don't need to request variable from SSM every time when lambda is triggered.